# Big query filter out numbers

Tags: google-bigquery

how to query data in big query that only outputs data with number in them , like filter out words vs words that has numbers , example
data is :

- ak4ppl
- 112sport
- 2 slots
- 451 slots
- online spins
- 300spins
- online cash

**my attempt**

```
SELECT
count (*)
FROM
  `lucky-antler-315014.th.st words`
WHERE
string_field_0 LIKE '%1%'or
string_field_0 LIKE '%2%'
```

**the results**

the total count for these two is 170, but its independent count for LIKE '%1%' is  145 and for %2% is  79 , yet the total count for the above attempt is only 170 when its should be total count of 224 when added right?

Comment: The `string_field_0` of a row can contain both numbers 1 and 2, e.g. "112sport", and then would appear in both independent queries, but only once in the combined query. So you can't simply add the numbers

Comment: you can use regular expression for this purpose

Comment: How do i exactly query all words thats has numbers in it? Im not sure by what you mean regular expression? Just  string_field_0 LIKE '%1%' ? And run? And then next string_field_0 LIKE '%2%' and run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was already suggested in comments  - you should use regexp as in below example

```
select *
from `project.dataset.table`
where regexp_contains(string_field_0, r'\d')
```

if applied to sample data in your question  - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So here you are not considering the case if the value has both '1' and '2' in it. so in this case if the value is '12-something' that will be counted both times you query the numbers individually. But in case you put a 'or' in query and check for any numbers then this value will be considered only once.

However, for this query I would suggest using regular expressions which might have been easier than the long query.

Answer (score 0):

i believe i got it now , in order for me to extract my desired --data containing numbers , i got the solution for it:

```
WHERE 
  string_field_0 LIKE '%1%'
  OR string_field_0 LIKE '%2%'
  OR string_field_0 LIKE '%3%'
  OR string_field_0 LIKE '%4%'
  OR string_field_0 LIKE '%5%'
  OR string_field_0 LIKE '%6%'
  OR string_field_0 LIKE '%7%'
  OR string_field_0 LIKE '%8%'
  OR string_field_0 LIKE '%9%'
  OR string_field_0 LIKE '%0%'
```